# Find closest number divisible by 3

Tags: javascript, math

I need to find a way to get the closest number divisible by three for a given number. As it's only the number three, and i was in a rush, i used if statements. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of getting the same result?

https://jsfiddle.net/

```js
let indexes = [0, 9, 26, 39];

for (let i = 0, l = indexes.length; i < l; i++) {
  newIndex = indexes[i];
  if (!(newIndex % 3 == 0)) {
    if (((newIndex - 1) % 3 == 0)) {
      newIndex = (newIndex - 1);
    } else {
      if (((newIndex + 1) % 3 == 0)) {
        newIndex = (newIndex + 1);
      } else if (((newIndex + 2) % 3 == 0)) {
        newIndex = (newIndex + 2);
      } else if (((newIndex + 3) % 3 == 0)) {
        newIndex = (newIndex + 3);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(newIndex);
}
```

---

```
input: 0
expected output: 0

input: 9
expected output: 9

input: 26
expected output: 27

input: 39
expected output: 39
```

Comment: What do you mean by cleaner? Less lines of code? As little new variable declarations as possible? Less if statements? Re-usability with integers other than 3?

Comment: [Many many dupes, JS and C# have near enough same syntax here](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+closest+divisible+by+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think i made it a little cleaner.

```js
let indexes = [0, 9, 26, 39, 29];

for (let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
  if(indexes[i] % 3 == 0) {
    console.log('Closest multiple: ', indexes[i])
  }
  else {
    if((indexes[i] + 1) % 3 == 0) {
      console.log('Closest multiple: ', indexes[i] + 1)
    }else {
      console.log('Closest multiple: ', indexes[i] - 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please comment if you need explanation.

Answer (score 0):

this switch case would make it better readable

```
function Get(input){
var number = input % 3;
switch(number){
    case 0:
        return input;
    case 1:
        return input-1;
    case 2:
        return input+1;
    default:
        return "somethign went wrong";
}
}
```

So now, you basically have to iterate through your array calling the function above.